# Perceived Performance vs. Actual Performance: How to bypass lengthly loading spinners?

Tags: mobile, loading

I have a loading spinner in between the login and dashboard sections of my mobile app. For "regular" users it would spin for a short, reasonable time (1-4sec) but for other users it may spin for 20 or even 30 seconds before proceeding to the dashboard (for technical reason which I won't detail here).

I am looking for a creative UX solution for avoiding the unhappiness involved in staring at a loading spinner for a long amount of time. What are best practice strategies to deal with such scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that will suit your case seems to be [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). Instead of loading all required data in one go, load it in a staggered manner.

Also, if your dashboard consists of independent sections visually separated by tiles, then instead of having a single loading gif in the center of the page, you may consider having a separate loading symbol on each tile.

In addition to this, if you have drill-down navigation on your dashboard to show more detailed data, then you can also consider loading only the top-level data (just enough to show the dashboard) and then load detailed information after the dashboard is rendered or on demand(user click).

That way, some of your users, instead of waiting for 20-30 seconds to interact with your application, they can get parts of it to interact with, sooner.